# Codeigniter - Script de instalação

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Criei um instalador para meu sistema ele instala normal, porém antes de finalizar a instalação ocorre o erro

```
Error Number: 1046

No database selected

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `auditoria` ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`usuario` varchar(45) NOT NULL, 
`data_hora` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
`operacao` varchar(45) NOT NULL, `query` text NOT NULL, 
`observacao` text NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Filename: C:\wamp\www\ehpcms\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

Segue meu controller instalar.php

http://pastebin.com/7W5YduaG

Comment: sugiro melhorar seu script. O que você está é chamado de DB migration (Aplicação criar estrutura do DB). Existem algumas formas de fazê-lo, mas a mais errada a se fazer é a partir do controller.

Comment: @gmsantos Pode me dar um auxilio então? Ou pelo menos me ajudar a corrigir este arquivo mesmo, estou começando agora, então para fins didátios já me ajuda.

Comment: meu palpite é que no momento que o controller é executado, o CodeIgniter carrega as informações dos arquivos config e depois que você cria o novo arquivo com as configs, ele ainda não foi carregado pelo framework. Isso explica ele rodar na segunda vez.

Comment: Uma abordagem que você pode utilizar é dividir a instalação em dois steps: um primeiro para as configs e um próximo para as tabelas.

Comment: Outra sugestão, mesmo sendo fácil o uso do framework, tente aprender a fazer umas coisas na mão mesmo, PHP puro. Didaticamente você tem mais a ganhar e vai saber se cara a diferença entre `write_file` do CI e `file_put_contents` do PHP

Comment: Compartilho a mesma opinião. 1º entre com os dados, submeta o form e crie os arquivos, e depois rode para criar as tabelas

Comment: Um lugar para começar: http://br.phptherightway.com/ :)

Comment: Vou primeiro tentar então submeter o form antes e depois criar as tabelas, vamos ver se eu consigo

Answer (score 1):

O erro informa que o Driver não encontrou o DB.
Você precisa alterar o DB no seu arquivo `application\config\database`.
Altere as linhas abaixo:

```
$db['default']['username'] = '';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = '';
```

Comment: Mas esses dados devem ser inseridos dinamicamente, na instalação do sistema, e não manualmente, entende?

Comment: Mas se você quer criar uma tabela, precisa informar a database...

Comment: No meu controller, eu to passando a variável database para o preenchimento.

Comment: Se eu tentar instalar o sistema 1 vez ele da o erro, na segunda vez não. Se eu não estou te entendendo me explica por favor

Comment: Acho que seu arquivo de config está sendo reescrito. Na 2ª vez que roda você gera com `$this->input->post( ... )`. Veja o comentário do @gmsantos. Mesmo que você tenha um instalador para criação de tabelas, nada impede de manter o config com os dados de conn.